# JProgressBar is not displayed

Tags: java, swing

I have the following code block:

```
JFrame progressFrame = new JFrame();
JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();
progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
progressBar.setString(selectedFiles[i].getName() + "is being processed ...");
progressFrame.setSize(400, 200);
progressFrame.add(progressBar);
progressFrame.setVisible(true);
try
{
  Thread.sleep(6000);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{ }
EvaluateLabsController.getInstance().evaluate(selectedFiles[i]);
progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);

progressFrame.setVisible(false);
```

But the progress bar is not visible, only an empty window is shown. Could you help me to understand why?

Comment: Do not sleep in the event dispatch thread. That blocks it, and prevents any drawing from happening. Instead show the progress bar, and then use a [SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) to do the task (whatever it is, that the progress bar is for) in the background.

Comment: If I run this the progress bar is shown correctly in indeterminate mode

Answer (score 0):

This code is working fine. This is a screenshot of the loaded window[image]